# MVC modular GUI components

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am trying to find the way to build complex web pages with MVC3 and AJAX.

I would like to use components to achieve this. 
Each component is consisted of it's own model, view and controller.

Multiple components are then placed on some complex view and should act together to
provide desired behaviors.

In some situations, when user performs some action (interaction) with one of the components,
I must update other portions of the page via AJAX. 
Component on which action (interaction) occurred, in it's implementation, does not assume anything about view on which it will be used and what portions of the pages should be updated and how.

So when some interaction occurs in some component, I need a mechanism (outside component itself) which will handle this situation and update appropriate parts of the page.
How would you, generally, implement such mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), also sometimes mistakenly referred to as the manager pattern.

This class would mediate the communication of your components.

Comment: For example, I have two components and a concrete mediator:

ComponentA (ModelA, ViewA, ControllerA).
ComponentB (ModelB, ViewB, ControllerB).

MediatorX (Knows ComponentA and ComponentB and how they should interact).

ComponentA and ComponentB are parametrized (model) and know that they are working with MediatorX.

Now, when user performs some activity, the action in ControllerA gets executed.

Comment: In this ControllerA action, I create MediatorX and call some method 
passing all relevant data - for example sender "ComponentA", 
action was "UserDoneSomething" and additional data is "123".
MediatorX then executes some action in the ControllerB and returns result which is then sent back to client.

Is this a good approach (or too complex) or I am missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your help... I will also post MVC and mediator implementation in the new question, as here it would be offtopic