# MVC and Mediator Pattern

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, mediator

I am trying to build set of reusable components for the ASP.Net MVC3 application.
Each component is consisted of it's own model, view and controller.

The interaction between components should be solved using mediator "like" pattern.

Since the components are higher level concept (abstraction) and not "real" objects (technically component is short-lived bunch consisted of a model, view and controller functions), it is probably tricky to implement
mediator pattern.

I need good ideas how to technically implement mediator interaction between components using ASP.Net MVC3 and AJAX?

My initial question with initial problem: [MVC modular GUI components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858937/mvc-modular-gui-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the controllers and views as simple and possible and create a service layer where all the interactions with other components and logic sits. Also I would create a separate project for the services layer so if you want to build different types of interfaces ( phone apps etc ) you can still use the same services layer. This would also enable some automated testing to check on the logic and interaction between your components. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a good idea and practice for more complex scenarios.
Let me clarify... 
I need simple example of mediator used strictly for the MVC GUI.
When something happens in some component (initiated by user activity), mediator would handle this situation and call appropriate components to generate output for the AJAX response.

Comment: I have done this very simply in ASP.Net Web Forms - component (user control which is an object) fires event which is handled by mediator (page which hosts components) and updates appropriate components.